# Estimate on total variation of composition of functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $f \in BV(\mathbb R)$ and $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be Lipschitz. How can I estimate  the total variation of $f\circ g$, that is
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} \left|\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))\right| dx \ ?
$$
For example is it true that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} \left|\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))\right| dx \le TV(f) \Vert g' \Vert_{L^\infty}
$$
holds?

---

Does the estimate improve if we also assume $g$ to be invertible?

---

As a bonus question: if we additionally assume that $g$ is a homeomorphism, is it true that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} \left|\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))\right| dx = TV(f) $$
hold?

Comment: You possibly mean "homeomorphism", not homomorphism. Yes, this is simply a change of variables formula. In particular it explains why the above inequality does not hold (compare $g(x)=cx$ for small and large $c$).

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks, I fixed the typo. Why doesn't the inequality hold? Which one holds instead?

Comment: choose $g(x)=cx$ with small $c$

Comment: @FedorPetrov This only suggests that the inequality might hold if you replace $\Vert g' \Vert$ with $\Vert (g^{-1})'\Vert$

Comment: If $g(x)$ is periodic, this is usually even infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ has a jump at 0, and $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ crosses zero infinitely often, then var$(f\circ g)=\infty$.

Comment: In this case $g$ is not invertible. Does the estimate change if $g$ is also assumed to be invertible?

Comment: If $g$ is a homeo, $TV(f\circ g)=TV(f)$.